# what does a dash in front of a pam entry mean?

Tags: linux, pam, gnome-keyring

I have searched everything I can but couldn't find any explanation.

My `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` file contains the following two gnome keyring entries:

```
auth        include     system-login
-auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
account     include     system-login
...
-session    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

why are both gnome_keyring entries prefixed with a dash?

I get two `gnome-keyring-daemon` instances running on login...Which seems to be a problem with `pass` (cli password manager). It stores the keyring password in session so I never have to enter the password with pass, which I don't like.

If I kill all gnome-keyring instances, after the gnugpg ttl caching times out, it prompts me again for the password...and that is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`man pam.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.conf)

> If the type value from the list above is prepended with a - character
> the PAM library will not log to the system log if it is not possible
> to load the module because it is missing in the system. This can be
> useful especially for modules which are not always installed on the
> system and are not required for correct authentication and
> authorization of the login session.